# create asynchronous and synchronous methods for a repository

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a repository with a method `Insert` that returns an `int` (the methods and types are not relevant here). I am thinking to create  `synchronous` and `asynchronous` insert methods for this repository. For the `asynchronous` method is it a good practice to enclose the `synchronous` `Insert` method in a `task` to avoid the code duplication?

Comment: You should write your async method from the ground up, using async versions of all methods available (for example, if you use Entity Framework - you have to use FirstAsync(), SaveChangesAsync and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not a good practice, as detailed by Microsoft's Stephen Toub here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/

... and by Stephen Cleary here:

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Long story short, if all your method does is wrap a synchronous call in `Task.Run`, that's trivial and I'm sure the caller is perfectly capable of doing it themselves. There is no need to increase the surface area of your API unless you have a naturally asynchronous operation (or unless you know that in the future you'll be able to provide one, and therefore want the consumers to target the `XxxAsync` method from day one).

As a bonus, here's a real life example of async wrapper methods being removed from a popular library:

JSON.NET used to provide `SerializeAsync` and `DeserializeAsync` methods which were just wrappers around their synchronous counterparts using `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Those were eventually obsoleted as they don't add value to the API and were deemed a potential scalability issue. The full discussion which led to this change can be found here:

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/66

Comment: here is a scenario: I implement this repository in a web api. The api method is async. From the link you've provided, I've understood that it's not ok just to wrap some code in Task.Run, so how to proceed in this case? Let's assume that the ream code it's an atomic instruction...

Comment: @BudaGavril, in scenarios where you *have to* provide a `Task`-returning method due to design constraints there are two choices depending on whether your consumers can tolerate a blocking call. In web API they can, because of the already asynchronous nature of the transport. So if your method does not include any other async operations (but has to return a `Task`), you just do your work as you normally would and return `Task.FromResult(...)` at the end. In situations where blocking would genuinely cause an issue for the consumer, use `Task.Run`, by all means.

Comment: P.S. This is actually a far more interesting question than the one asked. Consider posting it as a separate question, complete with a code example. I barely scratched the surface in my comment above.